# Can't connect and getting a "unhandled socket.io url" error with MAMP + Socket.io (node.js)

Tags: codeigniter, node.js, mamp, socket.io

I'm developing an application using CodeIgniter on a MAMP server (for development, live it'll be on LAMP). I'm trying to add the real-time functionality of socket.io for a chat server, but I'm having some issues. I have socket.io and MAMP up and running independently, but I can't get my client to talk to my server.

server.js:

```
// Get the Socket.io module
var io = require('socket.io');

console.log ( 'Chat Server started' );

// Create a Socket.IO instance, listen on 8084
var socket = io.listen(8084);

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 

  console.log ( "Server Connected" );

});
```

My client script (the socket.io.js loads fine and my console says "debug: served static content" whenever I load the page):

```
<script src="http://localhost:8084/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // Create SocketIO instance, connect
    var socket = new io.Socket('localhost',{
      port: 8084
    });
    socket.connect(); 

    socket.on ( 'connect', function () { console.log ( 'Client connected' ); } );
</script>
```

After starting the node.js file, I get this in my console:

```
Chat Server started
info  - socket.io started
```

After loading the client (directing my browser to http://localhost:8888 - the default port for MAMP), I don't get any of the console messages, but instead a steady stream of this (about every second):

```
info  - unhandled socket.io url
```

It looks like it's not connecting at all. Also, no errors in my JS error console on the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with a try / catch around your connections to see if any exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: `try { socket.connect() } catch (err) { alert ( err ); }`

No alert.

Comment: You include the JavaScript from port 3478, listen to Socket.IO on port 8084, and serve content on 8888. Is one of these wrong? I feel that newer versions of Socket.IO don't need the configuration options for `new io.Socket`--it figures it out based on how the JS was included.

Comment: I guess a better question is, what version of Socket.IO are you using? :)

Comment: @brandon Yeah, that was just a typo as I was trying to trouble shoot. I've tried many different ports (ensuring they're all the same), to no avail.

As for version:
Socket.IO.js build:0.8.5, development

Comment: I think you should be using `io.connect` instead of `new io.Socket`. Check out [this wiki page](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7+).

Comment: Killer! I'm getting connections. 

Man, I really wish the wiki for socke.io was better. Like a function list would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running socket.io version 0.8.5, I finally got this working using the following code:

server.js

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    express = require('express'),
    app         = express.createServer('localhost'),
    io          = require('socket.io'); 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);

var server = io.listen(app); 

server.sockets.on('connection', function (client){ 
    // new client is here!
    client.send ( 'Now connected!' );

    client.on('message', function () {

    }) ;

    client.on('disconnect', function () {

    });

});
```

client script:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var socket  = io.connect('http://localhost:3000'),
        text = $('#text');

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            text.html('connected');
            socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                text.html(msg);
            });
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            text.html('disconnected');
        });

    });

</script>
```

With everything up and running, upon going to my page, I see "Now connected!" almost immediately. I'm also serving my page up via CodeIgniter on MAMP - everything is working!